# Python list changing value outside the loop. Absolutely baffling

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

So, I was implementing a simple do-while in python. Everything goes as expected, except the moment I exit the while loop, the appended list inexplicably changes value.

I included print statements all over the place. The list is correct till the very last statement. Then the code doesn't even enters the while loop again, but somehow the list value changes?!?

Here's the code-

```
condition = True
while condition == True:
    bindigits.clear()
    for i in range(0, 7):
        if data[a][0] % 2 == 0:
            bindigits.append(0)
        if data[a][0] % 2 == 1:
            bindigits.append(1)
        a = a+1

    if bindigits == [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]:
        condition = False
    else:
        binletters.append(bindigits)
        print('binletters is now', binletters)
    print('checking while loop condition')
print('exited while loop')

print('binletters is now', binletters)
```

Here's the output (from where it goes wrong):

Binletters is now [[1,1,1,0,0,1,1],[1,0,1,1,0,0,1]... (relevant values) ]

Checking while loop condition

Condition false

Exited while loop

Binletters is now [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0].. (all zeros)]

Tried everything. Gave up. Please help!!

Comment: `binletters.append(bindigits)` isn't appending a copy of `bindigits` - every element you're appending to `binletters` is the exact same list, and the loop terminates when that list's contents are `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

Comment: If you check again, you should see that even when you thought the values were correct, later values were actually overwriting previous values.

Comment: If you have made a mistake in the code of your question, then please don't show the correct code in a comment. Instead, *edit your question* accordingly so that it shows the correct code.

Comment: Damn yes you are right. How do I add new bindigits to binletters?

What I am trying to do is-

1. Bindigit reads 7 bit value from a data list 
2. Adds that as an element of Binletters
3. Bindigit resets itself and does that for next 7 values

So that in the end binletters is a list of (list of 7 bits)

Comment: try `binletters.append(bindigits[:])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually add every time a bindigits cleared (I guess clear update it with all zeros).

What you need to do is after updating binletters with append to create new bindigits instance. you can add before the clear method `bindigits=[]` so it would be new instance.

Also, what [venky_ suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387387/python-list-changing-value-outside-the-loop-absolutely-baffling/46387528#comment79732604_46387387) will work from the same reason:

```
binletters.append(bindigits[:])
```